# How to read full case comment in Salesforce Lightning?

Tags: case, case-comment

On the Salesforce Lightning Case page, I can see the last 3 comments in the right shelf with the full comment body but when trying to read older comments, I click into the "Case Comments" list which only shows an unclickable list of comments with a cut off body. The body preview seems to be 400 characters after which it is cut off by an ellipsis. This too short as the case comments I'm reading are often email messages.

The "Case Comments" list is at a URL with the following pattern:

[https://my.lightning.force.com/lightning/r/CaseComment/{caseCommentId}/related/CaseComments/view](https://my.lightning.force.com/lightning/r/CaseComment/%7BcaseCommentId%7D/related/CaseComments/view)

This issue seems to be related to the following where the workaround is to use the Feed view, but I don't know what the Feed view is.

> If you are viewing the Case in Lightning, you can view the Case Comments in the Feed view.

https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000jkmKQAQ

How can I read the full case comments in Salesforce Lightning, and how can I bring up a case comment as a webpage, e.g. caseCommentId in the URL.

For now, my team has advised me to switch to Salesforce Classic to read case comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you click the down arrow on the comment column (when viewing all comments on a case), you'll see two options:

- Wrap text
- Clip text

I believe "clip text" is selected by default. Changing that to select "wrap text" shows you the entirety of the comment. No, I don't want to talk about how long that took me to realize, what an odd question to ask...

The "Feed view" being talked about are the "Details Comments E-Mail/Chatter Files Visibility" tabs that appear under the record header in Lightning. Selecting the "Comments" one obviously shows you the comments, though there are some pretty serious UX blunders Salesforce made in that view (the comment body is likely much longer than everything else. Why is it constrained to 25% of that component?)

I don't believe there is a standard way to view an individual comment in Lightning. The closest we have is to edit the comment (which pops up a modal box).

Comment: Awesome! Thanks!